# How can I unit test method that uses argument of type Part?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a web application project (non-spring) that has a method with argument of type Part (javax.servlet.http.Part).
In servlet value is supplied as:

`request.getPart("picture")`

Is there any way to set non-null value of this type without non-mock request?

Regards,

Comment: You can either mock it or you can implement Part interface and use your own custom implementation for the purpose of testing. Seems like you can easily implement this interface and read from a file when you implement getInputStream() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are facing trouble with getting object related to an interface you can create a class that will implement the interface and use it to create an object. 
I up voted Sap's comment.